# How to format datetime with the datetimepicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is a format like this:

```
Thu ,  13 March 2013 03:28pm
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
   dateFormat : 'D , d M yy hh:mm'
});
```

This is the result I got:

```
Thu , 13 March 2013 hh:03
```

What can I do to get the desired format?

Comment: see here http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-UI-Changing-the-date-format-for-Datepicker-P1023.html

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Comment: What datetime picker are you using?

Comment: I have searched about it all of these websites but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: cant you just edit it in the JS? D = Day , d = day in number, M = Month yy= year hh =hour mm= minute? so if you want 10:00 21.3.2013 you change it after dateformat : to mm:hh d.m.yy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve it since `dateFormat` is just for `datepicker`, you need to achieve it through `timepicker` as well. Here is a blog stated how you can obtain it:

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Answer (score 1):

See this:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwHe5/)

**[Reference Link](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)**

```
 $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'D , d M yy', timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'
});
```

In it small `m` is represent the numeric month. 
Above code will work for you.
For reference check [this link](http://timjames.me/jquery-ui-datetimepicker-plugin).

Comment: Thu , 21 0303 2013 h:March TT this is the result that i got @OSSCube Solution

Comment: @phireak can you post the link of datetime picker jquery that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box the jQuery UI datepicker does not provide the time as a possible format.  See the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

Comment: In your link there is no format for the time, there is only date format.

Comment: @OSSCubeSolution Thats my point, out of the box its not possible.